# What "futuristic" songs play during Bioshock Infinite and when?

Tags: bioshock-infinite, game-music-identification

**Minor spoilers warning**

We learn during the game that Albert Fink, Jeremiah's brother, was able to listen to music through Tears and claim it as his own. During the game, you can hear "oldified" version of songs that came out after the game's timeline.

I've heard Cyndi Lauper's "Girls Just Wanna Have Fun" through a tear (but not its old version) and during the end credits I've heard a version of "Everybody Wants to Rule the World" by Tears For Fears (Ha!).

What is the full list of all the futuristic (as of 1912) songs that appear during the game and when do they appear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

| Song | Location |
| --- | --- |
| **God Only Knows** by The Beach Boys | [Welcome Center](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Welcome_Center) |
| **Girls Just Wanna Have Fun** by Robert Hazard (another version was recorded and popularized by Cyndi Lauper) | [Battleship Bay](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Battleship_Bay) |
| **Tainted Love** by Ed Cobb (originally recorded by Gloria Jones) | The Graveyard Shift (the bar in [Shantytown](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Shantytown)) |
| **Fortunate Son** by Creedence Clearwater Revival | [Bull Yard](https://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Bull_Yard) |
| **Shiny Happy People** by R.E.M. | [Port Prosperity](https://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Port_Prosperity) |
| **Everybody Wants To Rule The World** by Tears for Fears | [Memorial Gardens](https://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Memorial_Gardens) |

<sup>Sources:

[BioShock Infinite end credits](https://youtu.be/0QZ4rIWHQD4?t=1207)

[BioShock Infinite IGN Wiki, "Secret Song Covers" article](https://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Secret_Song_Covers)

[@hammar's comment on this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114764/what-futuristic-songs-play-during-the-game-and-when#comment154078_114766)</sup>